# Using multiple authorization types with AWS AppSync GraphQL APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

[This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/) shows how to set multiple authorisation types to models and fields in graphql transform.

Lets say I have an `@model Blog`

```
type Blog @model {
   id: ID!
   adminUserId: String
   name: String!
   posts: [Post] @connection(keyName: "byBlog", fields: ["id"])
}
```

Using this shcema will autogenerate the following mutations/queries;
`createBlog`
`updateBlog`
`deleteBlog`
`getBlog`
`listBlogs`

I want `createBlog`, `updateBlog` and `deleteBlog` to have authorisation type `@aws_iam`.
I want `getBlog` and `listBlogs` to have my default authorisation type `@aws_cognito_user_pools`

How can I define this in my `schema.graphql`?
I can not set the authorisation type directly on the mutations/queries as they are not defined in my `schema.graphql` file.

I am able to set the auth types directly in the complete schema that is generated in the cloud (`AWS AppSync > API Name > Schema` ) because here all the queries/mutations are all defined. But this schema will be re-written every time I run `amplify push`.

There must be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

FYI I worked it out. The answer is the auth directive.

This schema will allow cognito (my default auth) to read only and iam to do everything. This is exactly what I want.

```
type Blog @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, provider: iam, operations: [read, create, update, delete] }, { allow: private, operations: [read] }]) @model {
  id: ID!
  adminUserId: String
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @connection(keyName: "byBlog", fields: ["id"])
}
```